# Screenshots aren't working on my Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, screen-capture, accessibility

I have an Apple Watch series 6 running WatchOS 7.5. I used to be able to take screenshots by pressing the Digital Crown and side button simultaneously, but this no longer works.

In Settings > General > Screenshots, "Enable Screenshots" is enabled. However, when I press the Digital Crown and side button simultaneously, my watch doesn't take a screenshot. Instead it appears to register the press on the Digital Crown first (so for example, if I'm on the home screen it opens the App view), then the side button a moment later (i.e. shows the app switcher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you have enabled a slower side button click speed in the watch's accessibility options.

Check in Settings > Accessibility > Side Button Click Speed

If your click speed it set to Slow or Slower, you'll see this behaviour.

You have two options to resolve it:

1. Set Side Button Click Speed back to Default
2. Leave Side Button Click Speed on its existing setting, but take a screenshot by pressing the side button first, then the Digital Crown a moment later. It takes a bit of practice to get the timing exactly right, but once you get it you'll find that this works.

*(Reported to Apple as FB9356332)*

Comment: Honestly, you’re a Saint. I loved taking screenshots of my watch timers for podcast data synchronization processes and also love fooling around with dumb software settings. I’ve just given up and called Apple after factory resetting the watch and so I really appreciate your insight here.